# Writing sections of javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the input gets blurred, I want to get the value of the input and replace the word "action" in the script, with the value of the input. So for example, if I type "hide" in the input, the word "action" would be replaced with "hide". Or something to that effect.

I'll then be using this logic to define the trigger (#elementA) and target (#elementB) also.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="define-action">

<script id="interactions">
  $('#elementA').click(function() {
    $('#elementB').action();
  )};
</script>
```

JS

```
$('#define-action').blur(function() {
  var action = $(this).val();

  // Replace "action" with action
)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use object `[]` notation

`$(selector).hide();` can be written as `$(selector)['hide']()`

So you could pass in variable instead of hard code string

```
$(selector)[action]()
```

Beware you will get errors thrown if method represnted by variable doesn't exist, so you should probably create an array of valid methods you will accept and make sure value is in the array before calling the method

Example of testing values in array:

```
var allowedMethods=['hide','show','slideUp'];
if( $.inArray( action, allowedMethods) >-1){
  $(selector)[action]()
}else{
    alert( action +' is not a valid method')
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "Property 'undefined' of object [object Object] is not a function". Is that what you meant by the errors? If so, could you elaborate a little please?

Comment: yes, that's sort of error. What methods do you want to support?

Comment: things like hide, show, fadeIn, fadeOut etc. I'll be editing this code a lot in future. Just trying to get something working for now.

Comment: Still not working. The alert says "undefined" instead of [action], so there must be a problem with getting the input value?

Comment: you had typo in `id="#define-action"` ...should be ..`id="define-action"`  WOrks here  http://jsfiddle.net/4JMF2/2/

Comment: *face palm* Thanks a mil mate. Works great :)

Comment: yeah..is a bit primitive yet...but you'll be able to build on it...might use `<select>` and build options from the array

Comment: I'm trying to get a variation working, setting the target too. I think it's just a syntax issue? I update the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4JMF2/3/

Comment: `$('#'+ target)`...can even see in syntax highlighter that target wasn't a variable

Comment: Ha this is sexy! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dot notation use bracket notation

Also I don't think you need to use the blur handler, in the click handler you can read the value of the input filed

```
$('#elementA').click(function () {
    var action = $('#define-action').val();
    $('#elementB')[action]();
});
```

or if you want to use the blur method then you need to define the variable `action` is a shared scope of both the click and blur handlers

```
$('#elementA').click(function () {
    $('#elementB')[action]();
});
var action;
$('#define-action').blur(function () {
    action = $(this).val();
});
```